# Showing Lipschitz continuity

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, lipschitz-functions

Let $f: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^m$ be a function with the property that for all $v \in \Bbb R^n$ an $L=L(v) \gt 0$ exists so that for all $x \in \Bbb R^n$ the function $t \longmapsto f(x+tv)$ is $L$-Lipschitz continuous.

Now i have to show that $f$ is Lipschitz-continuous.

Any ideas or tips on how to do this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: To all these 'close' voters saying this is 'off-topic' -- can anyone of you please _explain_ (I mean really pinpoint) what exactly is off-topic in this question? Is this something personal, a hunt or something? For this question my not be well researched, but it is _not_ off-topic. This kind of voting for close is much worse than what you seem to be fighting in my opinion.

Comment: I'm not sure what the notion of $L$-Lipschitz continuous is.  Would the OP add this definition to the Question, or give a reference to where it can be found?

Comment: @ I read this as 'Lipshitz continuous with Lipshitz constant $L$', and it seems that this was correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose a basis of vectors $e_i$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and, for given $x\neq y $ let $$ x- y = \sum_i a_i e_i$$
Then
$$|f(x)-f(y)| = |f(x)- \sum_i (f(z_{i})-f(z_i)) - f(y)|$$
where $z_1= x - a_1 e_1$,  and $z_2 = z_1 -a_2 e_2$ and so on, so $y =z_{n-1}- a_n e_n$
so by rearranging

(i.e. by writing

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
|f(x)-f(y)|&\le & |(f(x) - f(z_1)) +(f(z_1) -f (z_2)) + \ldots +(f(z_n)-f(y)) | \\
&\le & |f(x) - f(z_1)| +|f(z_1) -f (z_2)| + \ldots +|f(z_n)-f(y) | \\
& = & |f(x) - f(x-a_1 e_1)| + \ldots +|f(z_i) - f(z_i - a_{i+1}e_{i+i})| + \ldots
\end{eqnarray}
$$
and now applying the Lipshitz contidition

$$|f(z_i) - f(z_i - a_{i+1}e_{i+i})| \le L(e_{i+1})| a_{i+1}| $$ for each $i$) you get

$$|f(x)-f(y)|\le \sum L(e_i) |a_i| \le \max_i{L(e_i)}\sum |a_i|$$
But $a_i  = x_i - y_i$ and it is a well known fact that for $x, y$ 
$$|x-y|_* :=\sum |x_i-y_i|$$
is a norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Since, on  $\mathbb{R}^n$, any two norms are equivalent (if you don't know this search for this here or google it), the result follows.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Could you further explain how exactly you rearrange and use the fact $f(x+tv)$ is Lipschitz to get to the $$|f(x)-f(y)|\le \sum L(e_i) a_i$$ term. I don't understand how you got there

Comment: @DeltaChief I added some remarks to my answer, I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now i understand, really elegant prove.